# How to move images in a grid box?

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I'm sorry I'm asking a lot of dumb question but how do I get a image to ex move all to the right from the center, or even just 1 inch to the left from center

http://jsfiddle.net/96d7udd7/

the HTML

```
<figure class="imgbox">
    <img src="img/1.jpg" height="400px" alt="image01"/>
    <figcaption style="background: rgb(53, 25, 10)">
        <h2><span>Coffe Name</span></h2>
        <a href="#">View more</a>
    </figcaption>           
</figure>
```

you can see the CSS on the jsfiddle link

Thanks a lot guys. This is the best community for beginners like me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have separated imgbox div from grid div and created the below rule for visual clarification

```
.imgbox{
padding :10px;
margin:10px;
width:400px;
}

img{
width:200px;
height:200px;
}
```

link for above code :
http://jsfiddle.net/96d7udd7/1/

now to align the image to left you have to just add `float:left;` or aligining left with measurement `margin-left:13px;` in

the link : http://jsfiddle.net/96d7udd7/2/